# After jquery removeClass countdown anyway start again

Tags: jquery, countdown

With a click on a div something happens and also I remove the class from the div, so that nothing happens if I click again on the div. But although the class is away, the next click starts also a jQuery function.

I want a button to click on and then happens:

- a. a div will hide after x seconds
- b. another div will show after x
  seconds
- c. a countdown runs to show, when the change will happen

That will work great.

If i click first on the button1, the countdown should start (it does).
If i click again on the button1 the countdown should not start again.
(But it does - although I remove the selector class with the first click)

How can I avoid, that the countdown starts again?

```js
$('.button1').click(function() {

  $('.output0').delay(10000).fadeOut(500);
  $('.output1').delay(10500).show(0);

});


$('.button1').click(function() {
  $('.button1').removeClass('button1');
});



(function($) {
  $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

    // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
      increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

    return $(this).each(function() {
      var _this = this,
        loopCount = 0,
        value = options.from,
        interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

      function updateTimer() {
        value += increment;
        loopCount++;
        $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

        if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
          options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
        }

        if (loopCount >= loops) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          value = options.to;

          if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
            options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0, // the number the element should start at
    to: 100, // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000, // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100, // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 0, // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null, // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null, // callback method for when the element finishes updating
  };
})(jQuery);


$('.button1').click(function() {

  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.timer').countTo({
      from: 10,
      to: 0,
      speed: 10000,
      refreshInterval: 50,
      onComplete: function(value) {
        console.debug(this);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}

.output0 {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
}

.output1 {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button1 button" style="">
  Button1 to show something after 10 seconds
</div>

<div class="output0" style="">
  I will hide after 10 seconds
</div>

<div class="output1" style="">
  I will show after 10 seconds
</div>

<div class="timer"></div>
```

View on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StefanSan/7p8g9Lnh/5/)
Or here on [live site](https://www.heilpraktikerausbildung24.de/heilpraktikerschule/testseiten/test-warenkorblinks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `.button1` element still has a click event listener on it, even if you remove the class from it.

A potential solution would be to use the `.one` function of jQuery. This will only allow the event to be run once per element per event type.
It will require your `.click` events to be merged into one function like so:

```
$('.button1').one('click', function(){

  $('.output0').delay(10000).fadeOut(500);
  $('.output1').delay(10500).show(0);

  jQuery(function($) {
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: 10,
            to: 0,
            speed: 10000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/